# Displaying the last session variable when refreshing the page

Tags: php

I usually have problems with sessions.

My problem is that: If I have a have a session variable that stores the typed email address

```
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['myemail'];
```

and then I want my page to display the entered email in the welcome page when the user clicks on login

```
echo '".$_SESSION['email']."';
```

my code works fine but when user2 logged in and user1 refreshed the page, the page displays Welcome user2 because the last session variable stores user2's email.

I am so sorry for this easy question but I am still learning PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** both users are on the same browser, at the same time (for some as for yet unseen reason), and **IF** they are not using different sessions, the session variable will get reused and overwritten.

Comment: Yes I tested it on different browsers and it worked well. Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `unset()` the SESSION or destroy the session, like this:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score -1):

Sessions are tied to a specific browser by the PHPSESSID cookie sent with each request. The only way one user's session could affect another is if both users are using the same physical computer.

I don't think you're having the problem you think you're having.

Comment: Actually yes I am using the same computer and the same browser to test my program, so that's why I get a problem with session. Ok thank you for your answer. I will test it on different browsers.